# how to list all project with clearcase ucm commands

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I want to list all projects that are in the clearcase ucm :

```
$>cleartool lsproject *
cleartool: Error: Unable to determine VOB for pathname ".".
cleartool: Error: Unable to determine VOB for pathname ".".
cleartool: Error: Unable to determine VOB for pathname ".".
cleartool: Error: Unable to determine VOB for pathname ".".
cleartool: Error: Unable to determine VOB for pathname ".".

$>cleartool lsproject
cleartool: Error: Unable to determine VOB for pathname ".".
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the pvob which references all UCM objects, including projects:

```
cleartool lsproject -invob \yourPVob
# Or, on Unix
cleartool lsproject -invob /vobs/yourPVob
```

If you want just the names, you can take advantage of some of the options of [`cleartool lsproject`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsproject.htm):

```
cleartool lsproject -s -invob \yourPVob
```

Make sure you have a 7.1.x recent enough version of ClearCase: this [IBM technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21412407) reports the `cleartool lsproject` command don't work well in 7.0.1.7 and 7.1.1.0.